# Get full word from MatchCollection C# not group

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have words suppose `A 1`, `A 12`,`A 123`, `A 1234` and same for `B 1`, `B 12`, `B 123`, `B 1234` where 123 means three digits
Now by the time I do this:

```
MatchCollection ForA1 = Regex.Matches(inFile, @"\b(A [0-9])\b");
MatchCollection ForA2 = Regex.Matches(inFile, @"\b(A [0-9][0-9])\b");
.... and so on for three and four digits and B; total 8 lines
```

to reduce the code I done this:

```
MatchCollection ForAB1 = Regex.Matches(inFile, @"\b(A [0-9]|B [0-9])\b");
MatchCollection ForAB2 = Regex.Matches(inFile, @"\b(A [0-9][0-9]|B [0-9][0-9])\b");
.... and so on for three and four digits; total 4 lines
```

Now I want to do this:

```
MatchCollection ForAB1234 = Regex.Matches(inFile, @"\b(A [0-9]|B [0-9]...
|A [0-9][0-9]|B [0-9][0-9] and so on for three and four digits )\b"); total 1 line
```

At this time after matches I do this:

```
foreach (Match m in ForAB1)
   {
     //many calculations on the basis of index and length etc
     }
```

What I want:

```
foreach (Match m in ForAB1)
   {
     if(Match is 'A [0-9]')
     {//many calculations on the basis of index and length etc}
     else...
   }
```

Is there anything else simple enough so that I do not need to repeat code simply because of different number of digits? I am looking for all distinct matches that I piped.

**Edit:** Real problem is I do not want to m.len and then check if it is A or B because in reality I have more than thirty such expressions

Comment: No offence but if you have -1 this question there should be proper reason for that and I think you can write it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure you only check for `A 1` type and not `A 11` type, you need to use something like

```
foreach (Match m in ForAB1)
 {
     if (Regex.IsMatch(m.Value, @"^A [0-9]$"))
     {//many calculations on the basis of index and length etc}
     else if (Regex.IsMatch(m.Value, @"^A [0-9]{2}$"))
     {//many calculations on the basis of index and length etc}
     else...
 }
```

Comment: Occurrences are not problem I already have MatchCollection that can look for as many occurrences as possible. I am looking for all distinct matches that I piped

Comment: Then why are you using `\b`? I guess you are looking for `^`/`$` anchors, like `@"^(A [0-9]|B [0-9]...
|A [0-9][0-9]|B [0-9][0-9] and so on for three and four digits )$"`

Comment: `\b` is not a problem match does work. Problem is inside `foreach` loop I want to do one thing if match is A 1 and another if it is A 11 it is like `(type1|type2)` was inside regex and now I want to see in MatchCollection if selected one is type1 or type2

Comment: So, does enclosing these patterns with `^` and `$` work?

Comment: how is it different?

Comment: Please check the update, I removed the previous answer.

Comment: what is use of {2} ?

Comment: `{2}` is a limiting quantifier, `[0-9]{2}` matches exactly 2 digits.